# Custom Shapely Cap style

Tags: geopandas, buffer, shapely

I am currently using shapely and geopandas to parse through a shapefile containing lines to build a rail network.

I am using shapely to create a buffer to identify sections of track that cannot be links because they approach at the wrong angle.  I am currently using the flat cap end style.

This works well but, but it doesn't capture everything. Is it possible to implement a custom buffer cap style that looks like the blue area in the image below?

This would address the current problem I have where the orange line is allowed to pass as a link where it shouldn't because trains won't make a 90 degree turn.  The red line is an example of a link that is currently caught using the flat cap that is built into shapely.

[image: example of desired buffer with example lines that should pass (green) and those that should fail (orange and red)]

Comment: How do you know which line is the main (black) rail? By some attribute? Can you share the data?`

Comment: Wait, why do you not simply calculate angles between lines?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  

@BERA I can share the data.  Just need to look into a good way to do that at work.  The black line is whichever link I am evaluating within the network.  I iterate through the entire network.  All of them are the black line at some point.

Comment: @geozelot I ended up calculating the angle to get this done.  I still use the buffer as one step because I have to also determine sections of track that are blocked if a train is parked on the black link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a triangular polygon and clipping that from a square end buffer:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon, CAP_STYLE
from shapely.ops import snap
import math


def clipped_buffer(line, distance):
    buffered = line.buffer(distance, cap_style=CAP_STYLE.square)

    # first (reversed) and last line parts
    for coords in [reversed(line.coords[:2]), line.coords[-2:]]:
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = coords

        # Get the angle of the line part
        line_angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))

        # calc angle of buffer in relation to line part angle
        a1, a2 = math.radians(line_angle - 45), math.radians(line_angle + 45)

        # length (hypotenuse) of line part to square buffer end points
        d = math.sqrt(distance ** 2 + distance ** 2)

        # Get square buffer end points
        x3 = x2 + (d * math.cos(a1))
        y3 = y2 + (d * math.sin(a1))

        x4 = x2 + (d * math.cos(a2))
        y4 = y2 + (d * math.sin(a2))

        # Create triangular poly snapped to existing buffer geometry
        poly = snap(Polygon([(x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]), buffered, 1e-09)

        # clip out the triangle from the end of the square buffer
        buffered = buffered.difference(poly)

    return buffered


buffer_distance = 1.5

line = LineString([(5, 0), (0, 5), (5, 10), (5, 15)])

buffered = clipped_buffer(line, buffer_distance)

# Just to demo and create below plot
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": buffered, "id": [1]})
ax = gdf.plot()
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": line, "id": [1]})
gdf.plot(ax=ax, cmap="Dark2")
```

[image]

Alternatively, to make the buffer use a custom angle, rather than 45deg:

```
def extended_buffer(line, distance, angle):

    # hypotenuse c and adjacent b lengths
    a = distance
    c = a / math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    b = math.sqrt(c ** 2 - a ** 2)

    extended_line = list(line.coords)
    buffer_corners = []

    # first (reversed) and last lines
    for i, coords in enumerate([reversed(line.coords[:2]), line.coords[-2:]]):
        (x0, y0), (x1, y1) = coords

        # Get the angle of the line
        line_angle = math.atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0)

        # Get extended point
        x2 = x1 + (b * math.cos(line_angle))
        y2 = y1 + (b * math.sin(line_angle))

        if i == 0:
            extended_line.insert(0, (x2, y2))
        else:
            extended_line.append((x2, y2))

        # calc corners of buffer
        al, ar = line_angle - math.radians(90), line_angle + math.radians(90)
        xl = x2 + (a * math.cos(al))
        yl = y2 + (a * math.sin(al))
        xr = x2 + (a * math.cos(ar))
        yr = y2 + (a * math.sin(ar))

        # triangle poly to clip out of buffer
        buffer_corners.append(Polygon([(x1, y1), (xl, yl), (xr, yr)]))

    # create extended line and buffer
    line = LineString(extended_line)
    buffered = line.buffer(distance, cap_style=CAP_STYLE.flat)

    # clip out the triangles from the ends of the square buffer
    for corner in buffer_corners:
        buffered = buffered.difference(snap(corner, buffered, 1e-09))

    return buffered

buffer_distance = 1.5
buffer_angle = 65

line = LineString([(5, 0), (0, 5), (5, 10), (5, 15)])
# buff = clipped_buffer(line, buffer_distance)
buff = extended_buffer(line, buffer_distance, buffer_angle)
```

[image]

Comment: @GarrettAnderson note I've updated my answer to use [shapely.ops.snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.snap) to fix an issue where the triangle didn't quite line up with the square buffer ends because of floating point imprecision.